# Unable to execute CMDSHELL code on sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cmd, sql-server-2014

I had tried all possible ways to execute the below shown code on SQL server. And I still have no result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Find what is running the service... `select * from sys.dm_server_services` then [check your folder permissions] (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771586(v=ws.11).aspx) and if this folder isn't on the same machine as the SQL Server instance then you'll need to use UNC

Comment: Side note.... your query is working. There isn't anything in that folder and that's why you aren't seeing any files and sub directorys.

Comment: @scsimon-Folder do contains files it in.Also i had tried with other folders.i am getting same result

Answer (score 0):

Cmd shell must be open:

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.  
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
-- To enable the feature.  
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx)

Comment: @jeffrey-I am using SQL Server 2014.And how do i check folder permissions??

Comment: These are just windows permissions. You can find out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

On which user the SQL Server enigine service is running? Does it have access to specific folder?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer